# Term for errors that are constant for a measurement

Tags: measurement, error

In my measurements, I am encountering errors that remain constant over a measurement but change from one measurement to another. The errors specifically are amplitude and phase errors resulting from different electronic components in a telecommunication chain. Are these errors called static errors or systematic errors in literature? I looked at their definitions but couldn't relate them to my case. Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: A more specific example would help I'm sure.

Comment: well to be specific, the errors are amplitude and phase errors resulting from different electronic components in a telecommunication chain.

Comment: How would these "change from one measurement to another" - maybe I just don't recognize what you mean?

Comment: When I carry out measurements for say 30minutes, the errors remain constant and affect different signals in the same way. But if say I repeat the measurements the next day or so, the errors change. So I am trying to figure out in which category of errors in literature they fit into. May be static, but not sure!

Comment: Do they really remain constant in that 30 minute time frame or does it only seem so because the components and the errors are drifting on a long time scale (days)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I carry out measurements for say 30minutes, the errors remain
>   constant and affect different signals in the same way. But if say I
>   repeat the measurements the next day or so, the errors change. So I am
>   trying to figure out in which category of errors in literature they
>   fit into. May be static, but not sure!

This sounds like a temperature (thermal) hysteresis measurement error - they are a big deal in voltage references (used inside measurement equipment) and can give annoyingly different results from one day to the next.

The other type of problem it might be is due to aging - if you are testing a relatively new device, it will age and the aging gives a bigger error in (say) the first thousand hours but then starts to settle time.

So there are two "subtle" mechanisms known but this assumes that your measurement equipment is from a reputable supplier, has a valid calibration certificate and is not damaged in a way that could affect accuracy.

[**Useful**](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj9u5T40dHJAhUH_w4KHU7qBnAQFggsMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linear.com%2Fdocs%2F4442&usg=AFQjCNEL1Am06cYYGsg3U2Wg2VcEDb1vAQ&sig2=PeuamfSIoR5gRt-dIEo4pg&cad=rja) and short document from Linear Tech on this problem

Answer (score 1):

The term I would search for in literature is *drift*, meaning a very slow change in parameters, often due to the mechanisms described by Andy aka (temperature and aging).  The opposite term to search for would be *stable* or *stability*.

For example, you could say something like:

- "the amplitude error stability is better than 1 mV over 1 hour"
- "the phase offset drifts by 0.01°/day"

A couple of related terms are:

- *Repeatability* refers to errors due to repeated runs on the same device under test using the same measurement equipment.
- *Reproducibility* refers to errors measuring the same device using different sets of measurement equipment.

Your measurements probably have some error due to drift in the device under test, but also some repeatability error due to drift in your equipment.

Answer (score 0):

- [Offset](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/offset): (Electronics) A small deviation or bias in a voltage or current.
- [Margin of Error](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20margin%20of%20error): an amount (usually small) that is allowed for in case of miscalculation or change of circumstances.
- [Round-off errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error):  Also called rounding error, is the difference between the calculated approximation of a number and its exact mathematical value due to rounding.
- Tolerance. A value of error from from the stated value, i.e. a resistor tolerance of 10% of the given resistance.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion; but I am still not able to figure out that in which category the "errors that remain constant over a measurement" fit in. The errors specifically are amplitude and phase errors resulting from electronic components.